# Multiple foreign keys to the same table in Cake PHP?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, orm

Cake has its conventions for automating some functionality interaction between it's models and the tables they reference.  Foreign keys should be called people_id, if they reference a table called people.  How do I handle a case where a row holds two people, and needs foreign keys for both people?  It's obvious that I can't duplicate the column names, having two people_id columns.

Consider a competition where you have two competitors.  Each competitor is represented by a row in the competitor's table.  The competitions table needs to refer to both of those competitors.  How can I do this wouldn't breaking the automatic functionality that Cake offers?

Comment: i don't think you can have 2 columns of the same name - `people_id` - why do you think obvious you can?

Comment: [By the looks of it](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto) , it is somewhat impossible to do this with the ORM. ActiveRecord design pattern is way too limited for this. Hell .. IMHO, its not even good from making simple `JOIN` statement, not to mention more complicated cases. Basically, you will have to manually write the queries and retrieve the data.

Comment: I found this link that describes how this process is done:http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/851/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model

Comment: Found this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844998/multiple-relations-to-the-same-model-cakephp

Answer (score 2):

I found a link that describes how to do this perfectly.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm